# How do I pass a View's Model back to the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<byte> File { get; }
    // Other stuff
}
```

Controller:

```
// Other code
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    // Do async stuff to generate a SomeModel
    return View(someModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(SomeModel someModel)
{
    return File(model.File.ToArray(), "application/zip", "SomeFile.zip");
}

// Other code
```

and this view:

```
@model MyNamespace.SomeModel
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", Model)
// Code to display other aspects of the model
```

When I click on the link, I get an error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

I tried making the `ReadOnlyCollection` a `List` and an array. I keep getting the same error. I tried dozes of other small changes that probably aren't worth going over here.

Ultimately, I need some way to pass the entire model that was given to a view back to a controller endpoint/action/method/whatever the correct term is. I need this so that the method on the controller can return `File(model.File, ...)`.

Side note: my next task after allowing users to download the file will be to add buttons to the view so users can retry uploads to various repositories. Again, the model will need to be passed back to the controller so the file can be uploaded alongside some other metadata that is on the model.

**Clarification:**

To add more detail since there seems to be some confusion:
The controller method SomeAction queries a database and transforms the data into some other object that gets serialized to JSON. Sometimes multiple objects that get serialized to JSON and compressed into a .zip file. Ultimately, I get a byte[] of that result and have to send it to three different places: a shared drive, and through two other APIs.

What I had planned to do is, in a controller method, query and generate that byte[] and attempt to upload it to those three places and capture if that upload was successful or not. I would then store that byte[], some metadata about the file, and the result of those three uploads and display them in a view.

In that view, the user can see the result of the three uploads and attempt to retry the upload, if it failed. The user would also have the option to download the file.

In either case (retry upload or download the file), I believe I have to send that byte[] back to the controller to then return a File result, or try to upload and return a View. In either case again, it would be easier to just send back the entire Model. The download method doesn't need the rest of the model, but who cares. The retry upload method needs the entire model because the APIs need arguments stored in the metadata on the model.

Comment: If I understand what you're *trying* to do... `DownloadFile` doesn't need the entire model, and it definitely doesn't need to client to supply it with the entire file.  All it should need is an identifier for the server-side code to find the file.  `SomeModel` would include that identifier and add it as a query string value to the link in the view.  Then `DownloadFile` would only accept that identifier, not an entire model, and would use that identifier to find and return the file.